# Is green tissue in the center of cherry tomatoes related to 'Yellow Shoulder Disorder'?

Tags: tomatoes, diseases

I've read about the "Yellow shoulder disorder" in tomatoes, and I was wondering if I have something similar going on with my cherry tomatoes.

Some of them do indeed seem a little less colourful on top,
but the most annoying part is this bit of green in the middle:

[image: Cherry tomatoe with green in center]

Is it because of this disorder?

Comment: Are all your tomatoes like that?  Or just the one?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of that might cause this is something called (believe it or not) Tomato Blotchy Ripening. Patches of harder, green bits occur almost anywhere in the fruit, often visible on the outside, sometimes restricted to the inside, as with yours. The cause of this isn't fully known, but it is believed to be a disorder caused by malnutrition, possibly of potassium, or a poor root system, or excessive heat in a greenhouse. Usually, the worst affected fruits are towards the bottom of the plant, but not always. I don't know how you've grown your tomatoes (in pots, or the ground, or greenhouse) nor how you have fed/watered them, so can't comment further.